# How do I filter a list in glom based on list index?

Tags: python, glom

I want to be able to filter out just 1, or perhaps all list items less than a certain index with glom, but the filter snippets in the snippet section of the glom documentation doesn't show me how to do that.

Example (keep just the 2 first items in a list):

```py
target = [5, 7, 9]
some_glom_spec = "???"

out = glom(target, some_glom_spec)

assert out == [5, 7]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question! The approach you've got in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57521922/178013) works, and you're on the right path with `enumerate` (that's the Pythonic way to iterate with index), but it could be more glom-y (and more efficient!). Here's how I do it:

```py
from glom import glom, STOP

target = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
spec = (enumerate, [lambda item: item[1] if item[0] < 2 else STOP])
glom(target, spec)
# [1, 3]
```

The third invocation of the lambda will return glom's `STOP` and glom will stop iterating on the list.

You can read more about `STOP` (the glom singleton equivalent to `break`), and its partner `SKIP` (the equivalent of `continue`) in [the glom API docs here](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#glom.STOP).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to do this so far is by enumerating the incoming target, converting to a list, and then have a lambda like in this [snippet](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snippets.html#filtered-iteration):

```py
target = [5, 7, 9]
some_glom_spec = (enumerate, list, (lambda t: [i[1] for i in t if i[0] < 2]))

out = glom(target, some_glom_spec)
```